# Composed Lightning Web Component with slots and conditional rendering

Tags: lightning-web-components, modal

**Use Case**

I'm building a LWC to use as a modal template (leaving a slot for the body) so all the logic from the modal can be handled  there and reuse it for multiple modals

---

**Example**

Here's the component, let's call it `modal`:

HTML:

```
<template>
    <template if:true={open}>
        <div>
            <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                <div class="slds-modal__container">
                    <header class="slds-modal__header">
                        <lightning-button-icon class="slds-modal__close" icon-name="utility:close" onclick={closeModal}></lightning-button-icon>
                        <h2>Test</h2>
                    </header>
                    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
                        <slot name="body"></slot>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';

export default class ModalTemplate extends LightningElement {

    @track open = false;

    @api 
    openmodal() {
        this.open = true
    }

    closeModal() {
        this.open = false
    } 
}
```

I'm using that modal component in another, let's call it `testComp`

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-button label="Show Modal" onclick={open}></lightning-button>
    <c-modal>
        <span slot="body">Modal body</span>
    </c-modal>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class Modal extends LightningElement {

    open() {
        this.template.querySelector('c-modal').openmodal();
    }
}
```

---

**Problem**

This works great the first time I open the modal using the "Show Modal" button, however when I close the modal and press again the "Show Modal" button to open the modal one more time I receive the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot redefine property: nodeValue
    at defineProperties (<anonymous>)
    at patchElementWithRestrictions (aura_proddebug.js:5005)
    at createElmHook (aura_proddebug.js:5088)
    at Object.create (aura_proddebug.js:5302)
    at createChildrenHook (aura_proddebug.js:5171)
    at Object.insert (aura_proddebug.js:5312)
    at createChildrenHook (aura_proddebug.js:5172)
    at Object.insert (aura_proddebug.js:5312)
    at createChildrenHook (aura_proddebug.js:5172)
    at Object.insert (aura_proddebug.js:5312)
```

I've noticed that if I remove the "sloting" capability from the `modal` component it works fine, it seems is related to trying to rebuild the slot.

What I'm doing wrong and how can I achieve it?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, it doesnt even call `slotChange` event as mentioned in the doc.https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_components_slots

Comment: You can force `overlayLibrary` to work with LWCs, though it's much cleaner to omit the footer at the moment. I've done this and it works surprisingly well.

Comment: Slightly different way to do the same - https://salesforcecodes.blogspot.com/2020/01/how-to-display-modal-window-using.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you have is that your modal is destroying the slots , but the component that define the slots is keeping they alive

Comment: You’re right, in the end I added the conditional rendering to the parent component, this way if the component is not rendered then the modal and the slotted content will be drestroyed and therefore once they’re created again it would be new slots, therefore no redefining issue